# static STL map of int and tuple returns 0

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, stdtuple

Building a calendar for my C++ class. I have a utility class of static methods and static containers. Most notably:

Dictionary.h

```
static std::map<int,std::tuple<std::string,int>>months;
static std::map<int,std::tuple<std::string,int>>::iterator mitr;
```

This map contains, as keys, months 0-11. The tuple value contains the string representation of each month and the number of days of each month. For instance:

Dictionary.cpp

```
map<int,tuple<string,int>> Dictionary::initMonths(){
   map<int,tuple<string,int>>m;
   map<int,tuple<string,int>>::iterator mapitr = m.begin();
   m.insert(mapitr, make_pair(0,make_tuple("January",31)));
   m.insert(mapitr, make_pair(1,make_tuple("February",28)));
   // insert remaining months...
   return m;
}
```

The problem occurs when I attempt to access this map from another class:

Calendar.cpp

```
Calendar::Calendar(){
  Dictionary::init();
  time_t t = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(chrono::system_clock::now());
  tm* t2 = localtime(&t);
  int mo = (t2->tm_mon);
  Dictionary::mitr = Dictionary::months.find(mo);
  cout<<(*Dictionary::mitr).first<<endl; // => 0
  cout<<get<0>((*Dictionary::mitr).second)<<endl; // nothing
  }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
void Dictionary::init(){
  packaged_task<map<int,tuple<string,int>>()>task3(initMonths);
  future<map<int,tuple<string,int>>>fu3 = task3.get_future();
  guarded_thread t3(std::move(task3));
  map<int,tuple<string,int>>months = fu3.get();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly do you init the map? Your Dictonary code shows a function `Dictionary::initMonths()`, which returns a map, but your example application code just calls  `Dictionary::init()`. If those functions are actually the same and this is just a typo, then you forgot to assign the return value of initMonths to the static `months` variable.

Just as a suggestion, having a map here seems really a bit like overkill - you actually don't want the property of map that it arranges sparse keys in a tree-like structure in this case. It might be easier (and faster, for what it's worth) to just use a vector or a fixed array and just access by index, without iterator etc.

Comment: The primary reason I use map here is to bind the month number index, the string name of month and the number of days in the month all together in one container.

Comment: that would still be possible with vector (and maybe even easier):
`std::vector<tuple<string,int>> months(12);
months[0] = make_tuple("January",31);
//...`

Comment: ... btw, is your original problem fixed?

Comment: Yes, I've since solved it. Vector of tuples works, but it was one among a few issues - including use of packaged_task when promise was a better option. Instead of taking no params and returning a container, I rewrote my init methods to take a reference to a promise and return void. I also removed the static declarations in the Dictionary class and instead included a Dictionary pointer as a data member of the Calendar class. Works like a charm now. I will credit you with an answer since it started me on the path to diagnosing several ills. Obliged.